# How to sort multidimentional array if comapare same value then depends on other key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am working on `usort` function, right now I have the array like this

```
$data = array(
        array('rank'=>8,'suit'=>0),
        array('rank'=>7,'suit'=>3),
        array('rank'=>8,'suit'=>2),
    );
```

When I am using `usort` function, it is as below

```
usort($data function($a, $b) {
            return $a['rank'] - $b['rank'];
        });
```

And i am getting below result :

```
$data = array(
            array('rank'=>7,'suit'=>3),
            array('rank'=>8,'suit'=>0),
            array('rank'=>8,'suit'=>2),
        );
```

But i want below result  :

```
 $data = array(
                array('rank'=>7,'suit'=>3),
                array('rank'=>8,'suit'=>2),
                array('rank'=>8,'suit'=>0),
            );
```

I want to first do ascending by rank, and if rank has the same value then I want to do descending order by suit, Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this result with `usort` function?

Comment: Panchal I have edited the question and upvote it as I like the question

Comment: thanks @AramGrigoryan

Comment: Add comma between `$data` and `function` like this  `usort($data, function($a, $b)`

Comment: I have a solution to sort by the `rank` key but before I post an answer, do you need to sort by `suit`key too ?

Comment: @AymDev  if rank value is same then only i need suit key as descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), this will sort `rank` in *ascending* order `suit` in *descending* order:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['rank'] == $b['rank']) {
        if ($a['suit'] == $b['suit']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $a['suit'] > $b['suit'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return $a['rank'] < $b['rank'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

---

I came across this logic by doing this several time using **PHP 7**'s [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).
Here's the same solution using this operator to sort the `rank` key:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['rank'] == $b['rank']) {
        if ($a['suit'] == $b['suit']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $a['suit'] > $b['suit'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return $a['rank'] <=> $b['rank'];
});
```

Comment: @NikulPanchal I think the other answer is pretty good too but I hope you got the logic of mine !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/en/array_multisort)

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $rank[$key] = $value['rank'];
    $suit[$key] = $value['suit'];
}

array_multisort($rank, SORT_ASC, $suit, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Or as [this answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#119291) you can use

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'rank'), SORT_ASC, array_column($data, 'suit'), SORT_DESC, $data);
```